# dplyr::mutate makes R crash with a 50k-row data.frame (but not with a subset of 6k rows)

Tags: r, dplyr

I couldn't find a reproductible example, so here is my data: http://huitzi.fr/data/data.RData

The file contains two data frames. The first one is `data`:

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   53435 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Date                : chr  "2014-09-22T08:00:00" "2014-09-22T08:00:00" "2014-09-22T08:00:00" "2014-09-22T08:00:00" ...
 $ Time.Spent..seconds.: int  408 288 91 40 16 9 7 5 4 2 ...
 $ Number.of.People    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Activity            : chr  "reddit.com" "facebook.com" "kvirc" "Google Docs" ...
 $ Category            : chr  "General Business" "General Social Networking" "General Communication & Scheduling" "Writing" ...
 $ Productivity        : int  2 -2 -2 2 2 -2 -1 1 0 0 ...
```

and the second one is `data.copy`, which is a subset of `data` with only 6179 rows.

I'm trying to run this code:

```
> data <- mutate(data,
+                date = as.Date(substr(Date, 1, 10), "%Y-%m-%d"),
+                time = as.numeric(substr(Date, 12, 13)),
+                day = weekdays(date),
+                week = format(date, "%W"),
+                year = format(date, "%Y"),
+                month = paste(substr(months(date), 1, 3), substr(year, 3, 4)))
```

But when I do, R crashes (I've tried with RStudio and the R Gui on Windows).

[image]

However, **if I run the same code on data.copy, it works well**. Also, if I do:

```
data$date <- as.Date(substr(data$Date, 1, 10), "%Y-%m-%d")
data$time <- as.numeric(substr(data$Date, 12, 13))
data$day <- weekdays(data$date)
data$week <- format(data$date, "%W")
data$year <- format(data$date, "%Y")
data$month <- substr(months(data$date), 1, 3)
data$month <- paste(data$month, substr(data$year, 3, 4))
```

it works well too. But I'd like to use dplyr since I just discovered it and want to get used to it.

Comment: I don't see what the problem might be, but I would attempt a binary search for the problem in your data.  Split the data in two parts, see which (if any) causes the problem, then split that part in two.  Iterate until the dataset is small.

Comment: have you tried making a copy of your WHOLE data set and seeing if that still crashes?   might be just a memory issue

Comment: works for me, R-3.2.1

Comment: @kasterma: I don't think the problem comes from the data, since it works when I don't use the mutate() function. Additionally, nongkrong could make it work.
Ricardo: I'm not sure to understand how to make a copy. I have 4GB of memory and the dataset is still relatively small (~400KB), so I doubt it's a memory issue. 

I uninstalled/reinstalled R (and RStudio) but the problem persists. 
Also, as mentionned in my comment of ExperimenteR's answer, it works "once" after I boot my computer and then doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I think this was a bug in mutate that should now be fixed https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1231